# XNA 2D game - behaves differently on friend's computer

Tags: c#, xna

I made a simple networking xna game using c# and lidgren. But velocity of objects are different on friend's computer - resolution of window is the same, fps are the same (both 60), application is the same, but he's character is just slower for some reason. For some time his velocity is equal to mine, but then it slows down again.
Other friends do have equal velocities as I do. What could be a problem? The program adjusts movement according to fps, so there is probably no problem in fps.

Comment: Draw and update loops are different. Maybe your Update loop is performing differently in his computer. Difficult to say without code.

Comment: Are you using distance moved = difference in time * velocity? Because if you are just moving on the update loop that could change the speed of movement on a slower computer

Comment: moved = difference in time * velocity - I use this. That's why I am wondering how could he move differently - only his computer does it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code its hard to say for sure.

> The program adjusts movement according to fps

Well it's generally better to think of animation as a function *elapsed since the last update* rather than *frames per second*. That way, the animation will take the same amount of real world time to complete regardless of FPS whether it be *fixed* or *variable* update.

Movement deltas should take into account **time elapsed since last game update** not *last/current FPS*.

e.g.

```
    public Vector3 Velocity;
    public Vector3 Position;

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        // Apply acceleration
        Vector3 acceleration = force / Mass;
        Velocity += acceleration * elapsed;

        // Apply psuedo drag
        Velocity *= DragFactor;

        // Apply velocity
        Position += Velocity * elapsed;
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: Position += Velocity * elapsed;   - This is exactly what I use.

Answer (score 0):

You said you're using lindgren to make it multiplayer? Maybe it's rubberbanding due to latency. Try checking it on 2 computers on lan to see if it resolves the issue.

Possible there's different settings to lindgren to specify how to handle syncing or prediction.